# Is there a possibility to get here maps api autocomplete method with typo fixing?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, here-autocomplete

For example when putting 'barclona' autocomplete response should be 'barcelona'

Answer (score 0):

Currently Geocoder Autocomplete API doesn't support auto correction.
What it supports :

 **street types abbreviated and spelled out**

 **Multi-language: Returns language that matches the input best**

 **Special characters, e.g. umlauts, accents etc.**

We will let this know to our team as suggestion.

Thank you!